# Update validation summary in 'real time'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

Hi I am using MVC4 with client side validation. This works great for showing validation messages next to the fields.

I have added a validation summary:

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

This works, client side 'n all. I would like it to behave differently though; currently the messages in the validation summary only change when the submit button is clicked. I would like them to be dynamically, populated in a similar fashion to each field's validation message.

Can someone suggest a way to achieve this ?

Any information on what triggers the summary update would be great.

Comment: "currently the messages in the validation summary only change when the submit button is clicked." Please create a fiddle/demo so we can see what's going on.

Comment: If you add a validation summary to any form you should see the result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've set up the validation summary to update in 'real time' also considering the following:

1. Update the summary **only** once it's visible (after page validate/submit)
2. Clear the summary when everything is valid

Let's extract the validator, overrride showErrors() and implement our logic:

```
var validator = $('form').data('validator');
validator.settings.showErrors = function (map, errors) {
    this.defaultShowErrors();
    if ($('div[data-valmsg-summary=true] li:visible').length) {
        this.checkForm();
        if (this.errorList.length)
            $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
        else
            $(this.currentForm).resetSummary();
    }
}
```

Since I'm using this solution for my entire site I've created the following init (onready):

```
$('form').each(function () {
    var validator = $(this).data('validator');
    if (validator) {
        validator.settings.showErrors = function (map, errors) {
            this.defaultShowErrors();
            if ($('div[data-valmsg-summary=true] li:visible').length) {
                this.checkForm();
                if (this.errorList.length)
                    $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
                else
                    $(this.currentForm).resetSummary();
            }
        };
    }
});
```

And here's the resetSummary used above:

```
jQuery.fn.resetSummary = function () {
    var form = this.is('form') ? this : this.closest('form');
    form.find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]")
        .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
        .addClass("validation-summary-valid")
        .find("ul")
        .empty();
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Works pretty well except that it doesn't show the summary again when the first error occurs. I think this can counts as an answer though, Thanks.

Comment: You can exclude if ($('div[data-valmsg-summary=true] li:visible').length) if you always want the summary to update, of course.

Comment: But if you want the update to kick in after a submit and keep updating even if everything is valid I think we need to hold that state. Eg. `$('form').data('updateSummary', true);`

Answer (score 3):

The client side summary seems to be generated when the whole form is validated, and you can do  this yourself by calling the valid() plugin method.  Add this after the jquery validation scripts.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(':input').on("keyup click", function () {
            $('form').valid();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The example events I have included are keyup and click but you can add to or remove from this space separated list.

Comment: Or even better, you could do it on $('form').on('change',function(e){ $(this).valid(); });

Comment: is't it far more easy than writing bunch of code ? then why lesser votes ?

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript:**

```
function resetValidationSummary() {
    var form = $('#myForm');

    var validator = form.validate();
    validator.resetForm();

    if (form.valid()) {
        $('.validation-summary-errors').addClass('validation-summary-valid');
        $('.validation-summary-errors').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');
    }
}
```

**Css:**

```
.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```